# Spring Boot Multi Project Maven Application Context Error

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, maven, spring-boot

I'm struggling with a multi-project setup with Maven. Everything uses Spring boot and Annotations.

I'm using one project for the data access. The configuration file is like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = { "de.bvk.infra.g_portal.dataaccess.Repository" })
@EntityScan
public class DataConfiguration {
}
```

The Repositories are used in Tests with `@Autowired`. This is running fine and I can run my tests in Eclipse and also with `mvn clean install`.

I have a second "service" project which depends on the "data-access" project. The configuration looks like this:

```
@Import({DataConfiguration.class})
@Configuration
public class ServiceTestConfiguration {
@Autowired
DataConfiguration dataConfiguration;

@Autowired
BenutzerRepository benutzerRepository;
....
```

I can run all the tests of the service project in Eclipse and it is working fine.

When I try to run the project with Maven, I get an `ApplicationContextError`:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: 
No qualifying bean of type [de.bvk.infra.g_portal.dataaccess.repository.BenutzerRepository] 
found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire
candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations:
{@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1301)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1047) 
...
```

Can you tell me why Maven is acting differently from Eclipse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apperently it was a simple Error.

I had to change

```
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = { "de.bvk.infra.g_portal.dataaccess.Repository" })
```

into

```
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = { "de.bvk.infra.g_portal.dataaccess.repository" })
```

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse has significantly more limited concepts of dependencies than Maven does; in particular, it doesn't respect scopes, so that you can refer to classes in test scope, for example, from your ordinary classes. I suggest starting by using `mvn dependency:tree` to make sure that you're including the things you think you are with the appropriate scope and then turning up logging for `org.springframework.data` to `DEBUG` to see what repositories are being registered.

Comment: I ran `mvn dependency:tree` and the data access project is listed in the service project